# Pandas dataframe.loc returns empty dataframe even though all values are defined

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using pandas to search through an excel sheet and return a row if two values defined earlier in the text are found; however `df.loc` is not working and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.
My code:

```
temperature
table_we_want = sheets_dict[substance]
print(f'temperature is {temperature}')
print(table_we_want)
row = table_we_want.loc[(table_we_want['Temp C'] == temperature)]
print(row)
```

The error message:

```
temperature is 5
   Temp C  Press kPa        vf      vfg       vg     uf      ufg       ug  \
0       5     0.8721  0.001000  147.117  147.118  20.97  2361.27  2382.24   
1      10     1.2276  0.001000  106.376  106.377  41.99  2347.16  2389.15   
2      15     1.7050  0.001001   77.924   77.925  62.98  2333.06  2396.04   
 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Temp C, Press kPa, vf, vfg, vg, uf, ufg, ug, hf, hfg, hg, sf, sfg, sg, sheet]
Index: []
```

Comment: well I don't see the word 'degrees` in the first print so not sure that output is coming from that code (or a typo?). But could be a type mismatch. Is temperature the string `'5'` or the int `5`, and same goes for the values in that column.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. You should check whether the dtypes of the column `Temp C` and of `temparature` are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting it to a string for filtering:

```
row = table_we_want.loc[(table_we_want['Temp C'] == np.str_(temperature))]
```